# Enter value to a text field in IE using vba application

Tags: javascript, html, vba, ms-access, web-scraping

[image]I have a Macro in Outlook with a custom form. I should be able to launch a website and enter that value into the text field of that launched IE page.

For Example: Code should be able to open https://idea.ca, once it launched it should enter value "1234" in the text field.

DOM Explorer: Input field name indicates as below when I manually enter it.

I was able to launch the website but unable to enter the value on the specific text field.

```
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Set appIE = Nothing
Dim objElement As Object
Dim ObjCollection As Object
Dim varResults As New DataObject

varResults.SetText "1234"
varResults.PutInClipboard


Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "http://acf2prod/WebAdminr15/pages/vantage.jsf"
With appIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set ObjCollection = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

Set appIE = Nothing

With ObjCollection.document
        .getElementById("inputTextId").Value = varResults.GetText(1)
End With
```

Getting Error "Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

`ObjCollection.document` won't work: there are limited properties for the collection, and `.document` is not a property or method of HTMLElementCollection/DispHTMLElementCollection (as you are declaring late bound). It is, for example, a property of InternetExplorer.

What happened with a straightforward assignment? You should be able to assign direct (or try the following left hand side with your assignment from clipboard)

```
appIE.document.getElementById("mdForm:commandLineID:inputTextId").value = "1234"
```